# filtering an importrange with a query in google sheets (timestamp troubles)

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, string-formatting, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a dashboard that is pulling audit data from another sheet that has entries coming in continuously over the week. This gets to be 15k+ entries and is really slowing things down. I want to import the audit data to my dashboard, but only the audits from today. Here is what I have so far

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(URL, "audit_data!A1:f"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 where Col1 = date '"&TEXT(G1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

the cell G1 that is referenced is

```
=text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

which I realize may be redundant. This keeps returning with an empty output and I think it's because the audit data I am importing has the timestamp in 2/25/2020 18:37:50. any way around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A1, "audit_data!A1:F"), 
      IFNA(DATEVALUE(IMPORTRANGE(A1, "audit_data!A1:A")))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 
  where Col7 = "&DATEVALUE(G1), 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(A1, "audit_data!A1:F"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 
  where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(G1,   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(G1+1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks for the response! i changed the G1 cell to say =today(), but i am still getting query completed with empty output. Could it be that the query is looking for yyyy-mm-dd but the audit sheet has the date in yyy-mm-dd hr:min:sec?

Comment: I tried to query search another column from the source sheet for a different variable and got the correct output. Is there way to force the source timestamp to conform to yyyy-mm-dd in the query string? it seems like the hour:minute:second is causing it not to get an exact match.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet (with some fake data if its sensitive)?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13i3QsOXF8MVIsYRGlnNWJwfhd2OGRPHSEy94M5-PlB8/edit#gid=0 is the test sheet im using, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0XcuGSBMjwWrUpirjD_w-wcbUP0n_rgA_WUHJQh-h4/edit#gid=0 is a mock up of where the data is coming from. i would like to import only today (2020-02-26) as opposed to the whole week (i included another day in the mock data) thanks so much for the help so far!

Comment: @PatRyder answer updated and here is the demo spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vad1xWK2WK1E1Dpe5b4My1AJnottomTS6WG4S6yXZO8/edit#gid=0

Comment: Awesome! thanks so much. Ill plug this in and see what I can do. Really appricate it.